# Botao com loop Eterno usando AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou usando um botao no qual tem uma chamada ng-click=BuscaCliente. Ele aciona uma função no controlado Angular porem fica em loop eterno. Como corrigir isso ?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="botao" align="right">
              <md-button ng-class="loading ? 'btnprimario  md-button loading' : 'btnprimario  md-button'" type="submit" ng-click="buscarCliente()" ng-disabled="!cpfValido" class="btngreen btnBuscarCli">Buscar Cliente</md-button>
    </div>
```

**Controller.JS**

```
vm.buscarCliente = function(){
      vm.loading = true;
      if (vm.cpf !== undefined && vm.cpf !=='') {
        return desbloqueioCartaoService.buscarCPF(vm.cpf).then(function(response){
          if(response.status===500){
              MensagemFactory.setMensagem('teste');
          }
          if(response.status === 200){
            MensagemFactory.setMensagem('sucesso','Sucesso.','CPF encontrado com sucesso! '+vm.cpf,false,vm);
            vm.loading = false;
            parent.cliente = {};
            parent.cliente.leituraCartao = {};
            parent.cliente.leituraCartao.cpf = vm.cpf;
            $location.path('/leituraDeCartao');
          }else{
            MensagemFactory.setMensagem('info','Informação.',+vm.cpf+' Desculpe, Não foi encontrado.',false,vm);
          }
        }).catch(function() {
          MensagemFactory.setMensagem('erro','Error.',+vm.cpf+' Não foi encontrado.',false,vm);
        });
      } };
```

**Imagem**

[image: Erro tela]

Comment: Só colocar `vm.loading = false` num finally.

Comment: manda o codigo por gentileza!

Comment: tem como impor um tempo em milisegundos ???

Comment: Observe que no início da sua função, a variável `vm.loading` recebe valor `true`, porém você só atualiza ela para `false`, quando dá status 200 (OK). Você deve atualizar ela para `false` quando der erro também e mostrar uma mensagem para o usuário. Debugue o seu código, veja se está passando pelo fluxo correto e retornando status 200, pois se o _loader_ fica aparecendo, o resultado provavelmente está dando erro.

Comment: tem como atribuir um delay ao button ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva, porque atribuir um _delay_ ao `button`? Não vejo necessidade disso, pois você não tem como saber o tempo exato que a requisição irá levar. Conforme eu falei, você tem que atualizar a variável `vm.loading` para `false` em todos os retornos do AJAX, assim você garante que o _loader_ irá sumir do botão, independente do status de retorno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resposta do Problema**

```
vm.buscarCliente = function(){
          vm.loading = true;
          if (vm.cpf !== undefined && vm.cpf !=='') {
            return desbloqueioCartaoService.buscarCPF(vm.cpf).then(function(response){
              if(response.status===500){
                  vm.loading = false;//finalizar o loop
                  MensagemFactory.setMensagem('teste');
              }
              if(response.status === 200){
                MensagemFactory.setMensagem('sucesso','Sucesso.','CPF encontrado com sucesso! '+vm.cpf,false,vm);
                vm.loading = false;//finalizar o loop
                parent.cliente = {};
                parent.cliente.leituraCartao = {};
                parent.cliente.leituraCartao.cpf = vm.cpf;
                $location.path('/leituraDeCartao');
              }else{
                MensagemFactory.setMensagem('info','Informação.',+vm.cpf+' Desculpe, Não foi encontrado.',false,vm);
              }
            }).catch(function() {
              vm.loading = false;//finalizar o loop
              MensagemFactory.setMensagem('erro','Error.',+vm.cpf+' Não foi encontrado.',false,vm);
            });
          } };
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex, para finalizar o loop basta apenas uma chamada:

```
 return desbloqueioCartaoService.buscarCPF(vm.cpf).then(function(response){
     vm.loading = false;
     //seu codigo
 },function(_error) {
     vm.loading = false;
 });
```

O que sugiro é criar um interceptador http passando como parâmetro a sua mensagem.

Se acontecer de vir um erro, seja ele 500 ou outro, ele não irá entrar na sua função, a não ser que você esteja tratando antes.

Segue um exemplo:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$window', '$q', function($window, $q) {
    var sessionInjector = {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status == 500) {
                //seu codigo                      
            } 

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}]);
```

Referência: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http